# How does Outlook 2003 autodetect Exchange 2003 settings?

Tags: exchange-2003

I know that Exchange 2007 has that cool new Autodiscover feature, but currently, whenever a new user logs on to the domain for the first time, their Outlook gets automatically configured with the settings for our Exchange 2003 server. Would this be a group policy that I should look up, or is there a similar feature in Exchange 2003 that will populate Outlook clients with the right settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it is automatically detecting things, or did somebody use the Office Custom Installation Wizard to pre-configure the correct settings?

See the `Outlook: Specify Exchange Settings` section in this document about the wizard.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2003-resource-kit/custom-installation-wizard-HA001152576.aspx